# Access parameter input changing the actual data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have four identical tables that I am trying to query across. One problem I am having is with parameters. I have a query to union the four tables together which works perfectly, until I add a parameter. The parameter changes the data in one of the columns.

```
PARAMETERS [Year] Text ( 255 );
SELECT main.Geography, main.Year
FROM ((((select Geography, Year from [Geo union CA] 
UNION SELECT Geography, Year FROM [Geo union CC] 
UNION SELECT Geography, Year FROM [Geo union PA] 
UNION SELECT Geography, Year FROM [Geo union PC])  AS main
LEFT JOIN [Geo union CA] ON (main.Year = [Geo union CA].Year) AND (main.Geography = [Geo union CA].Geography))  
LEFT JOIN [Geo union CC] ON (main.Year = [Geo union CC].Year) AND (main.Geography = [Geo union CC].Geography))    
LEFT JOIN [Geo union PA] ON (main.Year = [Geo union PA].Year) AND (main.Geography = [Geo union PA].Geography))
LEFT JOIN [Geo union PC] ON (main.Year = [Geo union PC].Year) AND (main.Geography = [Geo union PC].Geography)
WHERE (((main.Year)=[Year]))
GROUP BY main.Geography, main.Year
ORDER BY main.Geography;
```

So I want the geography and year related to that geography (financial statements). Without the "Where (((main.Year)=[Year]))", I get the correct information of geography and related year. With it and the parameter, the geographies come out but with the years being whatever I put into the parameter.

For some additional context, the [Geo union XX]'s are a simple query to pull Geography and year from the initial data tables. This seemed to speed up the query time significantly.

Comment: What is `Year` supposed to be in these situations? ... `SELECT Geography, Year`  Is that the name of a field in the table, the `Year()` function, or your `Year` parameter?

Comment: What happens if you change the parameter's name from `Year` to `pYear` and then bracket the field names like this? `SELECT Geography, [Year]`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I guess I should have actually read how a parameter worked. Thought it needed to be the same name as the field but obviously that doesn't make sense for using it in a query

Answer (score 1):

`Year` is a reserved word (see http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) so:

- stop using reserved words.
- try using `main.[Year]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem stemmed from my use of "year" for both the field name and parameter name. Changing the parameter name to pYear fixed the problem.